# playorm for cassandra and play framework2.0.4

Tags: playframework-2.0, cassandra, playorm

I tried the https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki/PlayFramework-2.x-support example for connecting cassandra1.1.9 with play framework2.0.4. But when I add

  `nosql.nosqltype=cassandra
  nosql.cassandra.clusterName=Test Cluster
  nosql.cassandra.keyspace=iyte
  nosql.cassandra.seeds=a:9160,b:9160,c:9160`

I got the error and couldn't fix.
`Expecting end of input or a comma, got ':' if you intended ':' to be part of the value for 'nosql.cassandra.seeds', try enclosing the value in double quotes, or you may be able to rename the file .properties rather than .conf` 
 I added playorm-1.4.4 and other 3 jars in input\libexclude, removed nosql.cassandra.seeds=a:9160,b:9160,c:9160 from application.conf. This is the error
`! Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->`

sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error [value Context is not a member of object play.mvc.Http]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(PlayReloader.scala:236) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(PlayReloader.scala:236) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:236) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(PlayReloader.scala:233) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4.apply(PlayReloader.scala:233) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$4.apply(PlayReloader.scala:231) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:183) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3.apply(PlayReloader.scala:231) ~[na:na]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3.apply(PlayReloader.scala:226) ~[na:na]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2.reload(PlayReloader.scala:226) ~[na:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at akka.dispatch.Future$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:195) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Future$$anon$3.run(Future.scala:194) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:94) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1381) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) ~[akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Bad, I gave the seeds as following:

```
nosql.cassandra.seeds= "localhost:9160"
```

as the other default properties in application.conf are given in double quotes.
Please define seeds in your application as

```
nosql.cassandra.seeds="a:9160,b:9160,c:9160"
```

and let us know if you still face issue.

So, the issue is indeed with wiki, that instead of copying properties from my test application, I took the whole text from play1 plugin. I will update that.

Comment: Thanks. I changed seeds like u said. However this time I am getting another error.play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception [NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/astyanax/AstyanaxConfiguration]. So it means cassandra is not involved as Dean said. Is it true?

Comment: Dean meant that the above error was not due to Playorm or Cassandra but something else. Actually the first error was due to Play framework itself. This NoClassDefFoundError means that the required jars are not in your project's lib directory. To save the time, you may copy all the jars from playorm's output/jardist to your project's lib(including the 3 folders).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I am using playorm with 1.2.x on 2 clients but don't use the play 2.0 plugin and have this exact setup in application.conf and I am guessing you get that exception from astyanax ?  (as at this point casssandra is not involved).  I will get vikas(the person that wrote it) to look at this on monday when he is in.

Can you paste the exception stack trace in there?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: Thanks, so what am I going to do for using cassandra with play framework. As I searched play1.x doesn't have support to use cassandra. exception stack trace is added...Please remember my application.conf is without  'nosql.cassandra.seeds=a:9160,b:9160,c:9160' now

Comment: I have play1.2.x working with a 6 node cassandra(and in dev, we frequently use a 1 node cassandra), I basically followed these steps(albeit before they were written but it looks like everything I did is there).... https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/wiki/PlayFramework-1.2.x-Support

Comment: oh, and both 1.2.x and 2.0 work with the inmemory version which I just LOVE since I don't have to restart the server in development and can just keep coding(I wish to god the 2.0 was that fast...we tried it but it was just slow and we will retry in a year or so hoping for speed improvements).